# multiple file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to implement customised multiple file upload.The user can select a number of files.He may add or remove the files dynamically.
After the user presses an upload file button the uploading starts.

I am creating a hidden file field behind a customised button.Whenever the user clicks on the button i call choose on the file field and store the value in an array.

On pressing the upload button i was trying to generate a form dynamically and assign value from array to file field of form. But it seems i cannot assign value to form.

Is there any workaround ?
Need help fast.
Thnx in advance !

Comment: please show up some code. I can't visualize what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the array to a string, like [in this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tostring_array). To be more specific, indeed, you can not store an array in a form field, but yo can store strings. Arrays can be converted to strings and visa versa, especially with single dimensional arrays it's no big deal, as you can see in the example.